# Print the following pattern in Python language

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to print the following pattern:

```
#   #
##  #
# # #
#  ##
#   #
```

I tried the following code:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,6):
        if j==1 or j==5 or j==i:
            print'*'
        else:
            print' '
        print
```

But the output is:

```
*







*

*

*





*


*



*



*






*

*

*







*
```

I am new to Python.Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Why do you think [nested-loops] is relevant to your problem?

Comment: For what it's worth... it printed fine on my screen.

Comment: `print "#   #\n##  #\n# # #\n#  ##\n#   #"`

Comment: Until this question is reopened: Add a `,` after the first two `print` statements to prevent them from printing a line break, e.g. `print'*',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly:

```
n=int(raw_input('n='))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        if j==1 or j==n or j==i:
            print'#',
        else:
            print' ',

    print
```

Answer (score 1):

your code works percectly, when you save every line in a variable before printing it

```
for i in range(1,6):
    s = ''
    for j in range(1,6):
        if j==1 or j==5 or j==i:
            s = s + '*'
        else:
            s = s + ' '
    print s
```

If you want to use more print commands, you should check out the post:
[How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: this does not match the expected output

Answer (score 0):

for i in range(5):
for j in range(5):
if j == i or j ==i or j==0 or j==4 :
print("*",end=" ")
else:
print(" ",end=" ")
print()